# Prove that the solution blows up.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the o.d.e . $y'=t^3(y^2-1)+\sqrt{y}$ for $t>0$ where $y(0)=1$.
Prove that the solution cannot be defined for the whole $[0,+\infty]$.meaning there is a T<+00 that y blows up.

Proof: $y'$ is continuous and greater than zero since $y'(0)=1$ so  $y'>0$ for an interval and y increasing in that interval. Now i need  a lower bound for $y$ that blows up at some time T.  IF i had $y'\geq t^3y^2$ i would then integrate and find a lower bound for y that blows up. But i cant find a good bound.

Comment: Do you need to show $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}y(t)=\infty$ or $\lim\limits_{t\to T}y(t)=\infty$ ? The first one is immediate since if bounded and increasing it would have a limit and this is not possible since $y'\to \infty$. I'm not sure about the second usecase...

Comment: I need  the second one . Ill edit the question.

Comment: One idea would be to consider $t$ as a function of $y$, in which case the claim is that $t$ approaches $T$ from below as $y\to\infty$. (At minimum, this seems a decent approach if one wanted to numerically evaluate $T$: doing so in Mathematica yields $T\approx 1.2$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the solution exists for $t \in [0,T]$, it is increasing there.  Let's say $y(t_1) = y_1 > 1$, where $0 < t_1 < T$.  Compare to the solution of $y' = t^3 (y^2-1)$ with initial condition $y(t_1) = y_1$, which can be obtained in closed form, and  goes to $\infty$ at finite $t$.

Comment: I solved that but i get an exponential function  which does not blow to some T.

Comment: Well, then you solved it wrong.  What did you get?

Comment: i got a fraction with 2 expontents and for the denominator to be zero i need some complex constant.

Comment: $y(t) = \frac{(1 - e^{(2 c_1 + t^4/2})}{(e^{2 c_1 + t^4/2} + 1)}$

Comment: Did you use WA ? I think it is an artifact of calculation, see with this [formulation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%3Dt%5E3%28y%5E2-1%29+where+y%280%29%3Da) and $a>1$

Comment: For that to be greater than $1$, $e^{2 c_1}$ must be negative.  Instead, write the solution as $$y(t) = \frac{1 + e^{2 c_2 + t^4/2}}{1 - e^{2 c_2 + t^4/2}}$$